# Linear Algebra problem involving $v^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $v,w$ be non-zero vectors in $\mathbb R^3$. Assume that the set of vectors orthogonal to them is a plane through the origin. Then each of them is a scalar multiple of the other other.

As usual, set $v,w=(\alpha_1,\beta_1,\gamma_1),(\alpha_2,\beta_2,\gamma_2)$ respectively. Then, $v^{\perp}$ is a plane through the origin with normal$=v$ and $w^{\perp}$ is also a plane through the origin with normal $=w$. We know that they are the same plane, and hence the normals must be multiples of each other, hence $(\alpha_1,\beta_1,\gamma_1)=\lambda(\alpha_2,\beta_2,\gamma_2)$ and hence, $v=\lambda w$.

Is it fine? Or some more details?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks for the comment

Comment: Think of the unit vectors in $x,y,z$ directions. The cross product $x \times y = z$ is a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $v$ and $w$ are not multiples of each other. Then they are linearly independent and hence span a plane. The set of vectors orthogonal to this plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a line, which contradicts the assumption. Hence $v$ and $w$ are multiples of each other.

Comment: Hi! Can you please explain me the geometric intuition of this? Why should the set of vectors orthogonal to a line be a plane?

Comment: @Shamim It's because the vector is on $R^3$, and since $dim(W)+dim(W')=n=3$, and dim(W)=1 when W is the subspace expressing a line, so the orthogonal component, which is $W'$ should have a dimension of 2, which is a plane.

Comment: Great i got it. Thanks!